# The audio on my computer isn't working after installing Ubuntu. sudo alsa force-reload isn't working. How do I fix it?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10

So, I've just installed Ubuntu on my computer a few days ago. I haven't been able to get the audio to work and have been searching for a fix.

So far, I've found these fixes:

- Open the terminal and use the sudo alsa force-reload command

  This didn't work for me and when I did the command, it gave me back a result that looked nothing like the result people said I should be getting. I've also tried purging it and that didn't help either.

  [image: Here are my alsa reload results]
- Check to make sure the audio isn't muted

  I want to say this is obvious but I suppose tons of people probably overlooked it before posting online. Either way, I'm certain it's not muted and have opened up the mixer as well to check.

Originally when I opened up the sound settings, I had the built in speaker in the output list and it just wasn't working even though the speaker worked fine when I had windows on here. I tried the test button and no noise came out of either side. I just did some commands from a different forum suggestion -

```
> sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio 
> sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get
> autoremove 
> reboot 
> rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse 
> sudo apt-get install pulseaudio 
> sudo alsa force-reload
> pavucontrol
```

and now my sound settings look different and I can't even click the dropdown list for output. The speaker is no longer showing up there so it DID do something. The issue with this fix is that A) alsa reload didn't work, as usual, and I had to reboot to get the terminal to work again. Then when I tried pavucontrol it said I had to install it first. I did that and then did the pavucontrol command and it tried connecting me to pulseaudio. It sat there, trying to connect, for over thirty minutes until I closed it.

Something is seriously messed up with my audio and I don't know if it's because I'm missing programs I need or if these are out of date for the version of Ubuntu I'm on (19.10) or what. I'm just getting really hopeless. I've never used Ubuntu before and I've been really enjoying it aside from the audio issue and I really don't want to have to go back to Windows :(

Comment: Start with `sudo lshw -c sound`.

Answer (score 0):

Is not an answer, but I can't write on comments. I had a similar problem before, and always the solution was: on `pavucontrol > Configuration > Turn off HDMI audio controller`. It seems that in my case the problem is the HDMI output of the video card, it did not detect that it is not connected.

I don't know if your problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395187/no-sound-and-sudo-alsa-force-reload-hangs/1398231#1398231).

Try to run following on terminal

`systemctl disable timidity`

The `timidity` converter is interfering with the sound.