# No sound, and `sudo alsa force-reload` hangs

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, I've had to run `sudo alsa force-reload` after rebooting or else I'll have no sound. However, after a recent system update, even this stopped working. Now when I run the command, I get the following output, and then the command hangs:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer).

Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer
```

I'm not sure why the modules are failing to be unloaded now.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. I found the solution [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20221017144137/https://newbedev.com/how-can-i-fix-having-to-type-alsa-force-reload-after-each-startup).

The sound was restored after running on terminal

`systemctl disable timidity`

Apparently, it is not a problem of ALSA itself, but this `timidity` converter. (well, with such a name...)

Comment: NOTE: This link is dead, however there's no action needed for moderation it was initially put here for attribution.  The answer itself remains an answer.

Comment: @ThomasWard as of 2022-10-17 16:40 the Link is alive. :). Anyway, I have provided now a "permalink" to the webarchive, that should last long.